# Does restarting docker service kills all containers?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm having trouble with docker where `docker ps` won't return and is stuck.

I found that doinng docker service restart something like
`sudo service docker restart` (https://forums.docker.com/t/what-to-do-when-all-docker-commands-hang/28103/4)

However I'm worried if it will kill all the running containers? (I guess the service do provide service so that docker containers can run?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the default configuration, your assumption is correct: [If the docker daemon is stopped, all running containers are shut down.](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/). But, as outlined on the link, this behaviour can be changed on docker `>= 1.12` by adding

```
{
  "live-restore": true
}
```

to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. Crux: the daemon must be restarted for this change to take effect. Please take note of the limitations of live reload, e.g. only patch version upgrades are supported, not major version upgrades.

Another possibility is to [define a restart policy when starting a container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/). To do so, pass one of the following values as value for the command line argument `--restart` when starting the container via `docker run`:

```
no                Do not automatically restart the container. (the default)
on-failure        Restart the container if it exits due to an error, which manifests
                  as a non-zero exit code.
always            Always restart the container if it stops. If it is manually stopped,
                  it is restarted only when Docker daemon restarts or the container 
                  itself is manually restarted. 
                  (See the second bullet listed in restart policy details)
unless-stopped    Similar to always, except that when the container is stopped
                  (manually or otherwise), it is not restarted even after Docker
                  daemon restarts.
```

For your specific situation, this would mean that you could:

- Restart all containers with `--restart always` (more on that further below)
- Re-configure the docker daemon to allow for live reload
- Restart the docker daemon (which is not yet configured for live reload, but will be after this restart)

This restart would shut down and then restart all your containers once. But from then on, you should be free to stop the docker daemon without your containers terminating.

---

#### Handling major version upgrades

As mentioned above, live reload cannot handle major version upgrades. For a major version upgrade, one has to tear down all running containers. With a restart policy of `always`, however, the containers will be restarted after the docker daemon is restarted after the upgrade.

Comment: `Crux: the daemon must be restarted for this change to take effect`

The [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/#enable-live-restore) imply that you can enable the feature without a restart; you tell the running docker daemon to reload its configuration after editing daemon.json. I haven't tested this however.